How to optimise the time for reading large delta table using python from azure functions
We have a datascience code which was running in databricks and we would like to migrate it to azure functions to reduce cost. For this, when we convert the pyspark code to python to read adls delta table, it is taking long time. The table is a huge delta table. Even after applying filters on partition columns it is taking time. How to resolve the issue?
Df= DeltaTable(path)
Dt =Df.to_pandas(partitions=[("fid","=","1"),("year","=","2024")])


What is the size of your table. Can you provide some sample data? Can you share the full code? And what is the existing partitions that have been defined on the delta table? From your snippet, it looks like you are reading the entire table to memory and then doing the filtering. Check this article for suggestions on how to read delta tables using python. https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/631

I have created below code to read and download the delta table as csv this will reduce the time required to read the delta table from ADLS account:-
Azure Functions Http Trigger:-
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import io

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    account_name = "valleyxxxx4"
    container_name = "data"
    folder_name = "delta_table"
    sas_token = "sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=xxxxxxxe=2024-05-27T17:07:04Z&st=2024-05-27T09:07:04Z&spr=https&sig=axxxxxxxAPT%xxxxxxxxx%3D"
    container_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
    folder_url = f"{container_url}/{container_name}/{folder_name}/?{sas_token}"

    try:
        
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=container_url, credential=sas_token)
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

        blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_name)

        dfs = []
        for blob in blob_list:
            if blob.name.endswith(".parquet"):
                blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
                blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()

                
                file_obj = io.BytesIO(blob_data)
                table = pq.read_table(file_obj)
                df = table.to_pandas()
                dfs.append(df)

        if dfs:
            combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
            csv_string = combined_df.to_csv(index=False)
            return func.HttpResponse(csv_string, mimetype="text/csv", status_code=200)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("No Parquet files found in the folder.", status_code=404)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error reading Delta table: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error reading Delta table: {e}", status_code=500)

Output:-


My delta_table in Databricks:-

